# textfield.value = "" not working in Firefox, but works in Safari/Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-ui, safari

I have a function that deletes a textfield (called `termsField`) and uses JQuery to empty the text from a div (called `definitionContainer`), and I activate the function when the user clicks on a button.

```
function clearText(target){
    var definitionDiv = document.getElementById("definitionContainer");
    $('#definitionContainer').empty(); //empty the div
    termsField.value = ""; //delete the text field
    $(target).val = "";
```

And this is the HTML for my textfield and button:

```
<input id="termsField" type="search" autocorrect="off" 
     placeholder="Type something!" maxlength="2048">

<INPUT type="image" name="Clear" alt="Clear Search" src="clearX.png" 
    height="22" width="22" onClick="clearText(this)">
```

Does anyone have any idea why clearing the `definitionDiv` works in Firefox but `termsField.value = "";` doesn't work? Both of these work fine in Safari and Chrome. I'm not bothering with testing IE since this is part of a web interface.

Comment: 1) where termsField is defined? 2) is termsField a node inside definitionContainer?

Comment: How are you declaring termsField?

Comment: termsField is the id of the text field. termsField.value = ""; works perfectly fine in Safari/Chrome/iOS/Android just not Firefox

Comment: that's why I prefer make some question instead of soon answering ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown where the variable `termsField` is defined. Maybe you haven't defined it, which is likely to be the problem, since not all browsers do the hideous thing (introduced by IE) of polluting the global object with properties corresponding to the IDs of elements within the document. The following works fine for me:

```
var termsField = document.getElementById("termsField");
termsField.value = "";
```

Also, although this is unrelated to the problem with `termsField`, jQuery's `val()` is a method:

```
$(target).val("");
```

Comment: I made your change. Even if I comment out //$(target).val = (""); it still works in Safari/Chrome (deletes text field and div), it's like that line doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, that line is redundant, since an input with type `image` has no visual representation of its value.

Comment: That worked... the 2nd code that you put. Thanks a lot. Also your explanation is very good about using IDs in the document to represent variables. I didn't realize that was a big problem but it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(target)[0].value = 'blah';
```

or

```
$(target).val('blah')
```

Also you do not have `termsField` defined anywhere. Please define it if you already haven't in an outer scope.

Comment: termsField isn't a variable it's just the ID of the textfield in my HTML and it works fine the way it is in Safari

Comment: If `termsField` is not defined and the code works, there is an issue with the **browser**. Please do things logically and define it.

Comment: Well, it's a long-standing feature of the browser. IE has been polluting the JavaScript global object with properties corresponding to element IDs for years. WebKit copied it.

Comment: @Tim Down - Yeah I suspected that was exactly it. One still shouldn't do things that way.

Answer (score 0):

right syntax is

```
document.getElementById('termsField').value = ""
```

assuming 'termsField' is the id, as you specified above.